# Where can I find old versions of linksys router firmware?

Tags: firmware, router

I've had a headache of a weekend after upgrading to the latest firmware for my wrt54g. Suffice it to say I'm not satisfied with the latest version. Now I'm looking around for the previous version of the firmware out there on the interwebs and am having trouble. I noticed that linksys at one point had an ftp site: ftp://ftp.linksys.com. There you could find old firmware for your device. It now appears defunct. Does anyone know where I could find old firmware versions for my wrt54g router?

**Update**
According to the live chat guy, there's no way to retreive old firmware through cisco/linksys.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know where you can get old versions of the firmware. You can however load the tomato firmware... which is much more functional than the linksys ones anyway.

http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any Linksys firmware archives, but if you are not satisfied with the OEM firmware why not try an open-source firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G/GL/GS/GX). It is relatively easy to flash and includes powerful features beyond what the stock Linksys software offers.

Comment: Another option is <a href="http://openwrt.org/">OpenWRT</a>, which is slightly more difficult to configure than DD-WRT or Tomato.

Comment: Yup that one is good too. Was just gonna add that to my solution.